# "undefined reference to" error while using global variables in VS code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I am learning C++ using Bjarne's book, everything was fine until I get to learn how to include header files.

My codes are as below:

my.h

```
#ifndef MY_H
#define MY_H

extern int foo;
void print_foo();

#endif
```

my.cpp

```
#include "my.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void print_foo() {
    cout << foo << endl;
}
```

use.cpp

```
#include "my.h" 

int foo = 7;

int main() {
    print_foo();
}
```

I put them under the same folder with no space in folder name, I opened a new window from VS code, then I ran user.cpp and get the error saying undefined reference to print_foo.

Did I miss some key steps using VS code? because I think the codes are correct.

Comment: I haven't received any error after code build. Code is building and running fine. You need to build whole project and not single user.cpp file.

Comment: Looks good to me. Make certain that my.cpp is being compiled by putting in some garbage that can't possibly compile, like a line of aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa, and seeing if you get an error message about the aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaas.

Comment: you should build **both** cpps not only one. add to a project and build the project.

Comment: may I ask how to build a project in VS code, some source online says open a new window is equivalent

Comment: never mind, I fixed it by installing an extension

Answer (score 2):

```
g++ my.cpp use.cpp -o main
```

use this in the terminal

Comment: this gives errors: g++.exe: error: main: No such file o64-r directory                         -w6
g++.exe: error: unrecognized commandb64 line option '-0'

Comment: Should be `-o` not `-0`